# Diagram software (for drawing spirals, circles - not charts) for Windows

Tags: windows, drawing

I am looking for software for drawing shapes and diagrams as distinct from charting software. I'd like to be able to draw a spiral with arrow heads each end. Or circular diagrams made up of two, three or more segments with arrow heads and other ends. Or spirals, loops, or circles on circles.

As explanation is less than adequate, let me offer some examples of the types of diagrams I want to create:

[image]
[image]

Does anyone know a Windows software that I can use to draw such drawings?

Comment: What price range? And are you looking to be able to draw such diagrams with some software or for software to do it for you automatically?

Comment: At first glance, this seems like a [state/event diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_diagram). Not 100%, but very, very close. If you don't get an acceptable answer, try Googling that term

Comment: I have used [Dia](http://dia-installer.de) for some engineering applications (as I have seen the subject, fuzzy logic), maybe that would be useful

Answer (score 1):

Rather than tools which let me draw diagrams, I always prefer tools which will generate diagrams, preferably from textual input.

And the go-to tool for that is [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org), and has been for decades.

As a very simple example, this input:

```
graph { 
    a -- b; 
    b -- c; 
    a -- c; 
    d -- c; 
    e -- c; 
    e -- a; 
}
```

generates this diagram:

[image]

Take a look at [the examples gallery](http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery.php), and I think that you will find that you have your answer. And, it is cross platform, and free.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mawg, GraphViz is a lovely product and very useful for social network diagrams and the like. It is, however, not what I'm looking for. I really appreciate you replying to my post. Thanks again!

Comment: Can you tell us what it is missing? Perhaps there exists a mod/plugin/extension which would help? Is it to do with annotation, or don't you like that fact that you have to provide a text file? The more detail you can give, then better chance that we can help you - which is what we want to do :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [yEd](https://www.yworks.com/products/yed/gallery) ? It's full of parameters, maybe some of them will help you ?

Here is one example among many others from the link above :

[image: yed example]